# Rails: state_machine method for this or later states?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, state-machine

Is there any way to access that functionality within the `state_machine` gem? Kinda like levels:

```
def check_if_editor
  redirect_to :root unless current_user.editor? OR ANY NEXT STATE
end
```

Can't find much in the docs. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is. I've come across the same requirement and solved it by creating a method that checks each acceptable state. I'm not entirely happy with it because if a new state gets introduced it potentially needs to be added to the list.

```
def after_state1?
  state2? || state3?
end
```

I saw a closed discussion on the state_machine gem (can't find it again now) where they said they didn't want to implement state ordering because it would make it too complicated.

Comment: That's a shame. It was half the reason I used `state_machine` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use state machine methods `state_paths` (which returns an array of transitions from one specified state to another) and `to_states` (which converts the result to a nice array of states).

```
redirect_to :root unless editor_or_later?

def editor_or_later?
  states_after_editor = current_user.state_paths(:from => :editor, :to => :some_end_state).to_states
  states_editor_or_later = [:editor] +  states_after_editor

  states_editor_or_later.include? current_user.state.to_sym
end
```